# Arduino Uno starter's kit and project

Tags: arduino, breadboard

Recently i bough an Arduino Uno, along with a breadboard starters kit (those two were bough separate) and i am trying to configure my first project. Looking to the breadboard instructions, if i am not mistaken, i am supposed to remove the ATmega328 from the Arduino and use the other one (the one included in the kit).

Question is: 'Can i leave it as is and then tell the program which one to use?'

I am a bit confused in that part since i am not really experienced in electronic engineering.

Comment: What's the "other one" ? Generally you shouldn't have to remove anything from any Arduino. Whats the kit you bought ? Link ?

Comment: It's an ATmega328 also. here is the link: http://www.robotshop.com/eu/redboard-arduino-compatible-breadboard-1.html

Comment: what confused me is the first picture of the assembly guide. (page 8) http://www.robotshop.com/eu/content/PDF/assembly-guide-dev-11038.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these chips is programmed with a bootloader. The bootloader allows you to program your arduinos. This [link](https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/) says that the Optiboot bootloader is the one thats used in the UNO. In which case, both chips are the same and can be swapped.

However, if you are new and learning, I wouldn't swap them. As Jey was saying, there is the potential to damage the chip by removing it, static discharge etc...

Comment: Alright i think i got it. Anyway i am new so i'll have to do some research before trying anything fancy..

Answer (score 0):

If you can plug it in and it works, I'd say keep the current chip in the Arduino board. Taking out microcontrollers is a great way to damage them: with static electricity, bent pins, or otherwise. Power up the Arduino, make sure the drivers are installed, and try to run the ["Blink" example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/blink). If it works, I wouldn't mess with it.

Comment: That's exactly what i am trying to avoid! You mean after connecting the two boards?

Comment: If you have the FTDI breakout board, use that. Otherwise, you have no choice to remove the atmega from the UNO IF you want to program the other chip.